# opendj's ldappasswordmodify command is not taking into account user password history or validation requirements

Tags: ldap, solaris-10, opendj

I am on a Solaris 10 machine with opendj 2.4.5 installed. I am attempting to set a user's password with the ldappasswordmodify command. In my application I want to be able to set their password without requiring the previous password. I still need the password to obey the history and validation requirements though. I have this working on a similar machine that I set up a while ago and am not sure how I did it.

This is how I am calling the command:

```
ldappasswordmodify -D cn=mgr -w mgrpw -a uid=user,ou=people,o=systems,dc=program -n newpassword
```

No matter what password I give it the command works and sets the password.

If I use the command and supply the old password like this:

```
ldappasswordmodify -D cn=mgr -w mgrpw -a uid=user,ou=people,o=systems,dc=program -c oldpassword -n newpassword
```

The history and validation requirements are enforced properly.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this or perhaps what to check on the working system to see how I did it before? I'm at a complete loss.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the manager account. Don't use it for anything actually. Use a user account. The manager account is for `slapd` itself. It bypasses a lot of security and overlays.

Comment: What other account could I use? To set a password without giving the old one, passwordmodify requires a bindDN and password. It's also what I do on the machine that is working properly.

Comment: Create an administrative account with the appropriate permissions, if you don't already have one, and use it for everything administrative. Never use the manager account.

Comment: Forgive me for being new, but what rights does the account need? I can't find the admin account's information to see what rights it has, so I'm not sure what to give the new administrative account.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was an issue in OpenDJ 2.4 and it has been resolved in later versions.
You might want to try with OpenDJ 3.0 which is the later release available.